# Extension operator in F#

Tags: f#

Disclaimer: I am very new to F#.

I created a custom type for which I have an addition function. I wanted to extend it to allow addition with the standard `+` operator (the type is simplified for conciseness):

```ml
type MyInt = {N:int}

let sumMyInt n1 n2 = {N=n1.N + n2.N}

type MyInt with
    static member (+)(n1, n2) = sumMyInt n1 n2

let n1 = {N=1}
let n2 = {N=2}

printfn "%O" (n1 + n2)
```

This works and prints `{N=3}`. I wanted to lift this operation to lists of `MyInt`, and [if I understand the MSDN docs correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#generic-limitation-of-intrinsic-and-optional-type-extensions) extending `MyInt list` requires extension methods. So I write:

```ml
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

let sumMyInts = List.map2 sumMyInt

[<Extension>]
type MyIntListExtensions =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline (+)(ss1, ss2) = sumMyInts ss1 ss2

    [<Extension>]
    static member inline SumMyInts (ss1, ss2) = sumMyInts ss1 ss2


let x = sumMyInts ns1 ns2
let y = ns1.SumMyInts ns2
let z = ns1 + ns2
```

Now `x` and `y` compile and work. `z` refuses to compile with error:

```
The type 'MyInt list' does not support the operator '+'
```

The most surprising part is that this compiles:

```
let z' = ns1.op_Addition ns2
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I define an extension operator?

Comment: It's not possible to define an extension operator and use it "correctly" today in F#. It's an in-progress feature here (the design space is greater than just operators): https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1043-extension-members-for-operators-and-srtp-constraints.md

Comment: While there is a workaround (See your accepted answer), I would recomment that you simply use map2 without creating any custom operators. That will (imho) result in much clearer code.

Comment: I agree with @Guran, be careful with custom operators :)

Comment: @Guran Fully agree, if I cannot overload the standard `+` then I see little value in introducing a special operator for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* do what you want to today in F#, see [this RFC](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1043-extension-members-for-operators-and-srtp-constraints.md).

What you *could* do is create a global operator that does this:

```
let inline (@+) (xs: 'a list) (ys: 'a list) =
  List.map2 (+) xs ys


> [1; 2] @+ [3; 4]
- ;;
val it : int list = [4; 6]
```

Explicitly not shadowing `(+)` here for obvious reasons :).
More about creating operators here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading#creating-new-operators